# Cannot connect to RabbitMQ using a C# service - None of the specified endpoints were reachable

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, windows-10

I have created a C# Windows service using the Windows sevice (.NET Framework) template to connect to RabbitMQ to run on Windows 10, but I get an Exception "None of the specified endpoints were reachable".
I am trying to connect to RabbitMQ on the same PC my service is running on.
When running the code in Visual Studio I am always able to connect, however when it is installed as a service it always fails at the factory.CreateConnection() method.
I have created a RabbitMQ user which is able to access the required virtual host, and my service is installed to log on as the Network Service account.
I have tried changing the RabbitMQ account from guest to another created account and also changed the service logon to NetworkService, and also tried my own account but always get the same error from the service.
I cannot see anything in firewall that would stop this from connecting.

This is using RabbitMQ 3.11.10 and Erlang 25.2

The RabbitMQ logs show this every time I try to connect using the service

```
2023-05-26 14:32:29.934000+01:00 [info] <0.306.1> accepting AMQP connection <0.306.1> ([::1]:63175 -> [::1]:5672)
2023-05-26 14:32:29.944000+01:00 [warning] <0.306.1> closing AMQP connection <0.306.1> ([::1]:63175 -> [::1]:5672):
```

```
//Set up the RabbitMQ queue
factory = new ConnectionFactory { HostName = "localhost", UserName = "username", Password = "password" };
queueName = controller.Settings.QueueName;
EventLogger.Log(String.Format("Setting up connection to the RabbitMQ queue {0}", queueName));
connection = factory.CreateConnection();
EventLogger.Log(String.Format("Created the connection"));
channel = connection.CreateModel();
EventLogger.Log(String.Format("Created the model"));
channel.QueueDeclare(queue: queueName,
                     durable: true,
                     exclusive: false,
                     autoDelete: false,
                     arguments: null);
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us your C# code for connecting.

Comment: RAbbitMQ and Erlang versions ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: We need to see more context from the RabbitMQ logs, as well as any exceptions your application is throwing.